# If $f$ is Lebesgue integrable on $[0,2]$ and $\int_E fdx=0$ for all measurable set E such that $m(E)=\pi/2$. Prove or disprove that $f=0$ a.e.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $f$ be a Lebesgue integrable function on $[0,2]$. If $\int_E fdx=0$ for all measurable set $E$, such that  $m(E)=\pi/2$. Is $f=0$ a.e. Prove or disprove

I could not figure out anything. Can a function be very oscillatory so that on every interval its integral is zero?

Any hint and approach are welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: let $A$ and $B$ be small enough (let's say $m(A)=m(B)<0.001$). Then there exists $C$ disjoint from $A \cup B$ such that $m(C)=\pi/2 - m(A)$. Using your conditions on $A \cup C$ and $B \cup C$ show that $\int_Afdm=\int_Bfdm$. Now consider the positivity and negativity sets of $f$. Show, that if one or both of them have measure zero you are done. Show that otherwise it will contradict previous argument

Comment: you mean assume that positive and negative sets of $f$ has positive measure, and pick $A$ from positive set and $B$ from negative set? This will force that f vanish on sets which have small measures and belong to positive set and negative set respectively, actually and consequently f vanishes on all positive set which is contradiction, so f can not have negative and positive set with positive measure, this means f is either non negative or non positive, and in both case I think we are done, thank you

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I meant )