# Let $f ∈ L_1([0,1])$ be a function such that $\int_E f(x)dx = 0$ for any measurable set $E ⊂ [0,1]$ of Lebesgue measure $0.99.$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $f ∈ L_1([0,1])$ be a function such that $\int_E f(x)dx = 0$ for any measurable set $E ⊂ [0,1]$ of
Lebesgue measure $0.99.$ Prove that $f = 0$ a.e.

Not sure how to start this question.  Any suggestions?

Comment: take a look here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/651565/if-f-is-lebesgue-integrable-on-0-2-and-int-e-fdx-0-for-all-measurable-s?rq=1

Comment: Hint to start: the integral of $f$ is the same on every measurable set of measure at most $0.01$. Next: the integral of $f$ is zero on every measurable set of measure at most $0.01$. Next: ...

Comment: How is this a *duplicate* of the question @mm-aops linked?  We have a different length, a different requirement for $E$, and a different measure for the set in $E$.  I have not taken Real Analysis, though, so these two questions may really be obvious duplicates--I just want to make sure people slow down and check.